# Python Scrapy, how to use ".lstrip"?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my simple google search result crawler using scrapy.

```
class GoogleBotsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'GoogleScrapyBot'
allowed_domains = ['google.com']

start_urls = ['https://www.google.com/search?q=apple&hl=en&rlz=&start=0']

def parse(self, response):

    titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/h3/div//text()').extract()
    links = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div/a/@href').extract()

    items = []

    for idx in range(len(titles)):
        item = GoogleScraperItem()
        item['title'] = titles[idx]
        item['link'] = links[idx]
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

However, there is "/url?q=" at some item['link'] as blows

{'link': '/url?q=https://www.apple.com/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwj398Kv177xAhUFUKwKHZ_qAKkQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw1rYEJO8-kDCh7A5C3AggNG',
'title': 'Apple Inc. - Wikipedia'}

I'd like to remove "/url?q.=" using ".lstrip("/url?q=")"but I don't know where to put this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.lstrip` as the following:

```py
for idx in range(len(titles)):
        item = GoogleScraperItem()
        item['title'] = titles[idx]
        item['link'] = links[idx].lstrip("/url?q=")
        items.append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you. it works, I have one question. The output CSV, link colume, this is not hyperlink. It is text for link address. Do you know how to make it on the code?

Comment: I don not know what do you mean with text but if you show me how the text is inside csv file will help me identify your problem

Answer (score 0):

Just a little warning on `lstrip` :

`.lstrip("/url?q=")` works here because url starts with 'h', so it stops stripping right after the '='. But be aware that lstrip will strip any character '/', 'u', 'r', 'l', '?', 'q', or '='.

`.lstrip("u=rlq/?")` would give the same result.

Example on how it works:

```
txt = "/url?q=lurq.com"
x = txt.lstrip("/url?q=")
print(x) # prints ".com"
```

I'd rather use `.replace('/url?q=', '', 1)`. The 3rd parameter is here to force removing only the 1st occurence.

These also work:

```
txt.replace('/url?q=', '', 1)
txt[7:]
txt.split('=', 1)[-1]
```